Uploadthing: Will onClientUploadComplete always finish before the upload promise resolves?
In the onClientUploadComplete of my file upload, I populate an input field value (via React-hook-form):
const { : startAvatarUpload } = ("avatar", {
  onClientUploadComplete(res) {
    if (!res.length) throw new Error("Avatar uploadResult empty");
    form.setValue("avatarUrl", res[0].url);
  },
});


When I upload the image, I store the promise in state:
<AvatarInput
  onFileSelected={(file) =>
    setRunningAvatarUpload(startAvatarUpload([file]))
  }
/>

The goal is to avoid submitting the form before the file upload has finished. So I await the stored promise in the onSubmit function:
async function onSubmit() {
  try {
    if (runningAvatarUpload) await runningAvatarUpload;

    // The promise has resolved so the URL form field should be set

    const values = form.getValues();

    await updateUserProfile(values);
    onOpenChange(false);
  } catch (error) {
    ...
  }
}

My question is: Is it guaranteed that onClientUploadComplete will have finished before the runningAvatarUpload resolves? Otherwise I might submit the form before the URL field has been populated.

I would advise against storing a Promise in React state.  Seems like an anti-pattern.

@LindaPaiste Why?

Because a Promise is an object that has its own internal state and it's mutable.  When dealing with mutable objects I would use a useRef instead of useState, which probably doesn't change your code much.

I think you're good in terms of waiting for the upload to finish?  TBH I would edit the upload code to add like a 5s delay to test it out and make sure.  But I'm confused by what's happening in your startAvatarUpload code and if it actually returns a Promise.

@LindaPaiste Thank you. I've added both the ref and the delay for testing purposes. I'm not getting a race condition and I also clarified this with the UploadThing team.
